# Google API login failed always: back to needing to authorize

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'd like to change my tags of a YouTube video using the YouTube Data API. But I'm already stuck on login:

My page shows the message: *You need to authorize access before proceeding.* I click on *authorize access* and select my Google account and then my YouTube channel, I select *allow* and get redirected to the login message.

The code is directly from the sample files on Github:

```
<?php

/**
 * This sample adds new tags to a YouTube video by:
 *
 * 1. Retrieving the video resource by calling the "youtube.videos.list" method
 *    and setting the "id" parameter
 * 2. Appending new tags to the video resource's snippet.tags[] list
 * 3. Updating the video resource by calling the youtube.videos.update method.
 *
 * @author Ibrahim Ulukaya
*/

/**
 * Library Requirements
 *
 * 1. Install composer (https://getcomposer.org)
 * 2. On the command line, change to this directory (api-samples/php)
 * 3. Require the google/apiclient library
 *    $ composer require google/apiclient:~2.0
 */
if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
  throw new \Exception('please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "' . __DIR__ .'"');
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * {{ Google Cloud Console }} <{{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'myID';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'mySec';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

// Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
$tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $htmlBody = '';
  try{

    // REPLACE this value with the video ID of the video being updated.
    $videoId = "Zqt-NvuMKYU";

    // Call the API's videos.list method to retrieve the video resource.
    $listResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos("snippet",
        array('id' => $videoId));

    // If $listResponse is empty, the specified video was not found.
    if (empty($listResponse)) {
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<h3>Can\'t find a video with video id: %s</h3>', $videoId);
    } else {
      // Since the request specified a video ID, the response only
      // contains one video resource.
      $video = $listResponse[0];
      $videoSnippet = $video['snippet'];
      $tags = $videoSnippet['tags'];

      // Preserve any tags already associated with the video. If the video does
      // not have any tags, create a new list. Replace the values "tag1" and
      // "tag2" with the new tags you want to associate with the video.
      if (is_null($tags)) {
        $tags = array("tag1", "tag2");
      } else {
        array_push($tags, "tag1", "tag2");
      }

      // Set the tags array for the video snippet
      $videoSnippet['tags'] = $tags;

      // Update the video resource by calling the videos.update() method.
      $updateResponse = $youtube->videos->update("snippet", $video);

      $responseTags = $updateResponse['snippet']['tags'];

      $htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Updated</h3><ul>";
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>Tags "%s" and "%s" added for video %s (%s) </li>',
          array_pop($responseTags), array_pop($responseTags),
          $videoId, $video['snippet']['title']);

      $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    }
  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

    $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
} elseif ($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID == 'REPLACE_ME') {
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Client Credentials Required</h3>
  <p>
    You need to set <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> and
    <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> before proceeding.
  <p>
END;
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
<h3>Authorization Required</h3>
<p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Updated</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

Would be great if someone has a tip for me.

Comment: Question cause by typos should be closed and deleted. As per _Fixed... was a space key inside secret_

Answer (score 0):

Fixed... was a space key inside secret